# Angular 2 accessing views

Tags: angular

When I try to to go to http://myapplication/unmanaged I get a 404 error. I can get this to work by setting use hash to true and having the hash tag in the url. However I cannot do that because I am attempting to pass in query string parameters during runtime and the hash tag messes that up. Is there a way to use the following url during application load time without using the hash.

***URL:***

http://myapplication/unmanaged/x14/3?mac=00:11:22:33:44:79

***Routes:***

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: StartPage
  },
  {
    path: 'unmanaged/:controllerId/:activeGroupId',
    component: UnmanagedPage
  },
  {
    path: 'edge',
    component: EdgeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DevicesPage, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'devices', component: DevicesPage },
      { path: 'device/:id', component: DeviceDetailsPage },
      { path: 'device-edit/:id', component: DeviceEditPage},
      { path: 'device-add', component: DeviceAddPage },

      { path: 'groups', component: GroupsPage },

      { path: 'cyber-score', component: CyberScorePage },
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfilePage },
      { path: 'profile-edit', component: ProfileEditPage }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'guest',
    component: GuestComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'device', component: GuestDeviceDetailsPage }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundPage
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use deep linking with PathLocationStrategy your browser tries to locate the resource named unmanaged on the server when you enter  http://myapplication/unmanaged. There is no such resource on the server hence you're getting 404. You need to configure a redirect on your server so it redirects unknown resources to the index.html of your app.Then Angular Router will parse your URL and go to the proper view. Read your server's doc about configuring redirects.

With hash in the URL, the browser just knows that whatever is after the hash is for client navigation and doesn't hit the server.